long form of acronyms not typeset correctly in headers
In a large document, I handle acronyms with the acronym package. In normal text that works fine, but in headers the expansion doesn't work properly. Example:

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[british,final]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{acronym,hyperref}

\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Gluconeogenesis}

\subsection{The first bypass: From pyruvate to \acf{PEP}}

\subsubsection{\Acf{PEPCK}}

In the cytosol, oxaloacetate is converted to \acl{PEP} by the cytosolic isoform of \acf{PEPCK}. The enzyme requires not only the Mg bound to the nucleotide, but also Mn as cofactor bound to Cys307.

\acs{PEPCK} expression is stimulated by glucagon, glucocorticoids and thyroid hormone via \acs{cAMP}-, glucocorticoid and thyroid hormone response elements in its genes. Its expression is repressed by insulin via the \acs{MAP}-kinase pathway.

\begin{acronym}
 \acro{AAA+}{ATPases associated with diverse cellular activities}{, common motive in proteins that link \acs{ATP} hydrolysis to some cellular function}
 \acro{AMP}{adenosine monophosphate}
 \acro{ATP}{adenosine triphosphate}
 \acro{cAMP}{cyclic \acs{AMP}}{, second messenger}
 \acro{MAP}{mitogen activated protein}
 \acro{PEP}{phospho\emph{enol}pyruvate}
 \acro{PEPCK}{phospho\emph{enol}pyruvate carboxykinase}
 \acro{YAC}{yeast artificial chromosome}{, used to clone large segments of DNA}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}

The \Acf{PEPCK} in the \subsubsection swallows the "Phospho", \acf{PEPCK} works as expected. Allegedly, the use of \ \ @Acf doesn't match its definition, followed by 3 more error messages

the xstring package that acronym uses to split the string does not like the \emph at all. Try with \robustify\emph.

No, sorry, that doesn't help. Neither does replacing \emph by \textit or leaving this command out altogether. The problem seems to be the capitalisation of the first letter.

Well it worked for me in a current texlive.

What could be the difference between TeXLife and MikTeX (updated yesterday)

it should work in miktex too. But just to clarify: \robustify\emph belongs into the preamble.

That was the misunderstanding, now it works. Thanks.
